# How to properly check if a date is same or after today with MomentJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I am trying to validate a field to not have a date before today. I am using MomentJS and the following functions:

- is a valid date and I am using `isValid()`
- is same as today or after and I am using `isSameOrAfter()`

This is how I am doing it:

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){
    const value = moment(new Date($('#field').val()), 'MM/DD/YYYY', true)
    console.log(value)
  
    //console.log(value.isValid() && value.isSameOrAfter(moment(new Date(), 'MM/DD/YYYY')))
    //console.log(value.isValid() && value.isSameOrAfter(moment()))
    console.log(value.isValid() && value.isSameOrAfter(moment(new Date())))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="field" id="field" />
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

I am not sure what I could be missing here but as you can see is not working and I have tried three different ways (commented on the snippet above).

One thing I had notice is that the `moment()` object return the date with the TimeZone format: `2018-08-10T04:00:00.000Z` could this be breaking the validation?

What I am missing here?

Comment: because your **value** is the starting date (00:00:00) you need to use **moment().startOf('day')**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the granularity of `moment#isSameOrAfter` by specifying the unit of granularity as a second parameter:

```
const value = moment(new Date($('#field').val()), 'MM/DD/YYYY', true)
console.log(value.isValid() && value.isSameOrAfter(moment(new Date()), 'day'));
```

Accepted units of time are: `year` `month` `week` `day` `hour` `minute` `second`. Without specifying the granularity, moment will default to milliseconds.

http://jsfiddle.net/dp7rzmw5/24211/

Comment: But what about if I want to validate `08/10/2015`? Will that validate as true for `isSameOrAfter`?

Comment: The function evaluates for `value`, so if `value` is the same day or after the date parameter passed into `moment#isSameOrAfter`, it will return `true`.